# Using the BLTouch to assist with manual bed levelling?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bed-leveling, calibration, bltouch

I struggle with paper levelling and find it to be excessively coarse and unspecific. I bought a 3DTouch, but I still need to make the bed generally level using the knobs. Otherwise, the print will be uneven.

Is there some method that would allow me to probe an area with the BLTouch, see the value, adjust the knob, and repeat? And do this at each corner?

I thought the G30 command in Marlin would achieve this, but I consistently get slanted prints when using G30 at each corner.

I thought this would be a very good approach, since the BLTouch is directly on the carriage, and I would be able see the height of each corner to a hundredth of a milimeter.

I tried searching for this online, but I couldn't find specific resources and what I am proposing seems to be very rare or doesn't even exist.

Is there a way I can use my BLTouch to assist with manually adjusting the knobs of my 3D printer bed?

Comment: Did you try bed leveling plugins in octoprint? I've been leveling bed using G30 with X &Y motors disabled for  a long time and it never went wrong.Depending on the relative position you install the 3d touch,you may not be able to probe using G30 at exact 4 corners.

Comment: What is strange is that I am getting the opposite of what I would expect with the G30 command. For example, at one of the corners, I probed and got 0.05. This would suggest that I need to lower the bed there to achieve 0.0. However, at this corner, I would expect to have to raise it based on the mesh print. When I do lower it, I end up with a slanted bed according to the mesh print, although G30 says it is at 0.0. So my problem with the G30 command is that it seems like it is telling me to lower the bed when I would think I would have to raise it and vice versa.

Comment: How did you use G30 to level your bed? Can you provide an answer with that?

Comment: use G30 at middle of the build plate and use that value as relative 0. So if G30 center returns 0.6,at the corner it’s 1.2,then the corner is 0.6higher.Absolute G30 value could be calculated (which I’m not sure) from raw data and a probe offset.Use relative data against G30 in the center should work just fine.

Comment: ender3 bed is known to be warped and especially on the corners.Mine has a 0.4higher corner than it’s in the center.It’ll be warped no matter how you level it with G30.This can be only compensated by ABL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use your BLTouch to assist with 'manual leveling', if your firmware supports it. To avoid confusion, the proper term for 'manually leveling' is 'bed tramming'. Some firmware has a 'Bed Tramming Wizard' like the [Marlin-based mriscoc firmware](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1). The [mriscoc's Bed Tramming Wizard](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/wiki/Bed-tramming-menu) is well documented.

Below is an example of how it would look on an Ender 3 V2 or S1.

[image: Bed Tramming Corners Not Leveled]
[image: Bed Tramming Corners Leveled]